# Is possible to design a book in Illustrator or Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, book, booklet

I have to design a book, It has 24 pages include the cover page, one of pages size is A4.. Let me know, What is the suitable Adobe software for my design.. Can't I design this book using Illustrator? Definitely should I use the Adobe InDesign?

Comment: It sounds like you already know that you should use Indesign. You could make it by gluing macaroni on sheets of paper, but Indesign will be easiest to manage.

Comment: yes I know, but I dont know InDesign, I know only Photoshop & Illustrator, that is why I want to know, Can I use the Illustrator for my design,???

Comment: That was what I was trying to say. You could use anything, byt Indesign makes the most sense.

Comment: If you know illustrator you should be somewhat productive in inDesign quite quickly (A hour or so)

Comment: yep I want know learn InDesign also.. I will try to learn InDesign quickly, as you told.. Thank you..

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's possible.

Would I want to do it? No way, except for a book of 24 pages of full-color photographs and no text. Then I might do it in Photoshop.

The thing about most "books" is that they contain linked columns of flowing text, plus generated text such as tables of contents, indexes, lists of illustrations, page numbers, and more. NONE of those is possible in image-editing or illustration programs. They are meant to be done in page-layout programs such as InDesign, QuarkXPress, and FrameMaker. And if you want running headers/footers, text variables, conditional text, master pages, xrefs, and many other book-level niceties, you must have a robust big-publication editor such as FrameMaker.

Answer (score 4):

Every Adobe product has a purpose for which it should be properly used.

InDesign is mainly used to organize text and images and design layouts like you can see mostly in newspapers and magazines.

Photoshop is usually used for editing "pixel" based images such as a photo. The advantage of using Photoshop is its ability to view effects as you apply them, and view them again instantly and easily if you come back to your work at a later time.

It's better to use these two tools in combination, Photoshop for the layout details while using InDesign for better text rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Illustrator is equipped for Book design if you do not have Indesign. Please keep in mind that the working file may become enormous unless you keep all the illustrations/images unlinked in the initial file. Photoshop is NOT a good option for typographic layouts, as it tends to encourage stretching/distorting fonts.